# How to update Indexed View in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexed-view

I am executing more than 40 reports on a daily basis using SSRS. These reports are using similar data-set with some changes on condition.

I think it is better to use an indexed view rather than tables; this will enhance the performance and reduce the time for each report.

But I do not know how to update/refresh indexed view after creation. The underlying table is updated every mid-night.

Comment: You don't. The data is automatically refreshed when data changes in the underlying tables. (That's why there are so many restrictions on indexed views - to allow this updating to happen with minimal "cost")

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.